# How to trigger Multibranch Pipeline Jenkins Job within regular pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to trigger a specific multibranch pipeline job '*maven-release-workflow-test*' (specific branch) within a regular pipeline job. Is there a special build() command pattern that i need to specify?

The snippet generator just prints:

*no such job maven-release-workflow-test*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the right pattern via trial and error:

```
build 'maven-release-workflow-test/master'
```

Comment: What if the branch name has slash (e.g feature/foo)? Should that be encoded?

Comment: I printed the job name of a multibranch pipeline that the branch contains slash, it showed something like `multibranch-pipeline-job/feature%2foo`. It seems that the slash becomes the UTF-8 encoding. And that weird name is able to trigger the job.