# Why am I getting an exception when attempting to kickoff a multibranch build job from a regular pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am doing something similar to the accepted response from [How to trigger Multibranch Pipeline Jenkins Job within regular pipeline job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322143/how-to-trigger-multibranch-pipeline-jenkins-job-within-regular-pipeline-job) .  I have a regular pipeline job that is attempting to kick of a multibranch pipeline job, for a particular branch that has already been scanned and registered.

The code looks like:

```
 rc = build job: mb_job_name, 
       wait: true
```

where `mb_job_name` contains the name of the downstream job plus the branch name.

The strange thing is that the downstream job actually starts and runs fine.  I see the expected:

```
Scheduling project: playground-sandbox » Chris » test-jenkins-mb » dv_main_117_chris2
```

output.  The problem is, in my regular pipeline job that kicks off the downstream job, just after the build job call, and the expected Scheduling... output, it throws an exception like:

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@28280b21
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@48fc924d
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@3b112c7a
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@a5e88d8
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@6faa034a
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@d6a022e
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@d6a022e
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1793)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor124.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.writeObject(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor146.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$0(RiverWriter.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:237)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:553)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:530)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:517)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:441)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

In a general sense, I understand that this means that I have code/variables that Jenkins can't serialize, but its unclear to me what it is.

I tried changing my code to the simpler form of:

```
build mb_job_name
```

and I also tried replacing the mb_job_name variable with a string literal with the name of the job, but no improvement.

*update*

It looks like it has something to do with the fact that I have the following code just before the build call:

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def pl = jsonSlurper.parseText(payload)
def repo_name = pl.repository.name
```

If I remove `def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()` then I no longer get the exception.  Unfortunately, I need to parse some JSON so I kind of need to create the object.  Probably need to use the @NonCPS annotation somehow.

Comment: Use `readJSON` utility step instead of `JsonSlurper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `JsonSlurper` inside the pipeline code, use `JsonSlurperClassic` instead. The difference is that the second one produces `LinkedHashMap`, a serializable object. The first one produces `LazyMap` which is not serializable.

There are different ways to parse JSON in the pipeline code, you can check this blog post for more information - https://e.printstacktrace.blog/how-to-catch-curl-response-in-jenkins-pipeline/#using-groovy-json-jsonslurperclassic-to-parse-the-response

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you need to use @NonCPS to tell Jenkins CPS that it is in a state where it can't serialize the program state. This is done by moving the non-serializable code into a function:

```
@NonCPS
def parseRepositoryName(payload) {
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def pl = jsonSlurper.parseText(payload)
    return pl.repository.name
}
```

Add this to the end of your code, and replace the old json parsing code with a function call to the new function:

```
def repo_name = parseRepositoryName(payload)
```

Comment: Well we tried this also. but it didn't worked. maybe it totally depends on jenkins version also.

Comment: If you still get serialization errors, then you have more code that needs to be inside NonCPS block.

Comment: Thank you.  This solution worked also, but I choose the use of JsonSlurperClassic as the best answer because it required less code changes and more flexibility.    I did have to change the last line of the function to `return(pl.repository.name)` .  The existing `return = ...` code resulted in an error.

Comment: Fully understand  thanks for pointing out the errer, I've update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The multibranch Job folder structure in Jenkins is different than a regular job and to trigger that from a remote job you have to specify 'JOBNAME/BRANCHNAME'.
Might be you have mistaken on that format, Hence it's erroring. Take a look on my below example.

```
node {
    stage('call multibranch pipeline') {
        def res = build job:'test0/main'
    }
}
```

in my example, `test0` - is the multibranch job name and `main` is the branch. I have not used `wait: true` because the `wait` default is True in `build` DSL

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I originally had that issue, and if you just specify the job name without the branch, it kicks off a scan, which is actually quite useful for me.  But that doesn't cause the exception.  I only get the exception when I specify it as "job/branch".  Its interesting that you don't see the error.  I am basically doing the same thing.  I see the Scheduling project: line in my output, but not the "Starting building:" line.